# Join for tally table. Need for each day each Cust_ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can you help to figure the way to produce that output table like on the pic below. This is part of membership/gap tricky processing I need. Could not figure out how to do this for EACH Cust_ID to have entry for each tally date.

Sample code: (* Last select need to be improved))

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
(
    Cust_ID VARCHAR(14), 
    Contr_ID INT, 
    ENR_START DATE, 
    ENR_END DATE
)

INSERT INTO #test 
VALUES (1, 1, '2018-1-2', '2018-01-5'),  
       (1, 2, '2018-01-7', '2018-1-8'),
       (2, 1, '2018-01-6', '2019-1-10')      ----- select * from  #test

SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Period_Start, @Period_End + 1))    ----- create tally
     DATEADD(dd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @Period_Start)  dt 
INTO 
    #c                             --   select * from #c   -- 10 days
FROM
    master..spt_values  

SELECT    
    t.*, c.dt 
FROM
    #c c   
LEFT JOIN   
    #test t ON c.dt BETWEEN t.ENR_START AND t.ENR_END 
ORDER BY
    1, 5
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the logic that you want:

```
select cu.cust_id, c.dt, t.*
from (select distinct cust_id from test) cu join
     c
     on c.dt between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-10' left join
     test t
     on t.cust_id = cu.cust_id and c.dt between enr_start and enr_end
order by cu.cust_id, c.dt;
```

The idea is to generate all `cust_id`/date combinations and then `left join` to the original data to get any matches.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9e2cd3f55e921ce8b80da7434219c5a) is a db<>fiddle.